# Error "Columns `x`, `y` must be 1d atomic vectors or lists" in hchart

Tags: r, dataframe, r-highcharter

I'm trying to draw a barplot in R using the `highcharter` library

My dataframe `mostly_used` looks something like this:

```
        word    n
1        sir 8484
2       time 7339
3       miss 5954
4       dear 5422
5       hand 5305
6       head 4978
7      night 4240
8        day 4124
9       eyes 4040
10     house 4011
```

and I use the following line of code:

```
hchart(mostly_used, x = word, y = n, type = "column", name = "word count"
       , color = "blue")  %>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_null())
```

I get the error `` Error: Columns`x`, `y` must be 1d atomic vectors or lists ``

can anyone explain why this is?

edit:

```
> dput(mostly_used)
structure(list(word = c("sir", "time", "miss", "dear", "hand", 
"head", "night", "day", "eyes", "house"), n = c(8484L, 7339L, 
5954L, 5422L, 5305L, 4978L, 4240L, 4124L, 4040L, 4011L)), .Names = c("word", 
"n"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: It is opening a browser tab with the message 'no data to display' in the center.

Comment: Can you `dput` your data, so we can see exactly what data types you're working with?

Comment: @camille i edited the question and added `dput`

Comment: I tried your code with your data, with `tidyverse` and `highcharter` loaded, and got an error. Restarted R, loaded `dplyr` and `highcharter` instead of `tidyverse`, and it works. So I think some tidy function must be conflicting with something in `highcharter`

Comment: @camille I don't have `tidyverse` loaded though I have `tidytext` but I don't know if it makes a confliction or not. so the error is irrelevant? It made me assume there was something wrong with my data types

Comment: Your code and data are both valid--I was able to get a bar chart using what you posted, once I unloaded tidyverse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the documentation and see the examples didn't use the syntax you tried. It appeared more functional. (My efforts preceded your edit that included the data example, so my `mostly_used` was just an ordinary dataframe, hence my use of `as.character` to coerce what I thought would be a factor. That turned out to be unnecessary but harmless.)

I took the line-type example from the vignette on my machine: http://localhost:13297/library/highcharter/doc/replicating-highcharts-demos.html and replaced the corresponding values:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Counts of Mostly Used") %>% 
    hc_xAxis(categories = as.character(mostly_used$word)) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "N")) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(line = list(
    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE),
    enableMouseTracking = FALSE)
    ) %>% 
  hc_series(
    list(  name = "Used",
      data = mostly_used$n
    )
  )
```

This is a screenshot of what appeared in my Chrome session:

[image]

Your comment with the citation to a different bit of documentation showed that there was an `hcaes`-function wrapped around the x and y argument assignments. This worked for me:

```
hchart(mostly_used ,type = "column", title="Counts of Mostly Used",
                     hcaes( x = word, y=   n)    )
```

The "why" is the need to respect that package's handling of non-standard evaluation. It emulates the ggplot2 package's strategy of using an "aes"-function to define the column names using real R names, i.e. unquoted tokens that are evaluated in the context of the data argument.

Comment: thanks, I upvoted since your code does exactly what I want though it doesn't answer what's wrong with my current code and why the error is produced. here's the link to what I used http://jkunst.com/highcharter/hchart.html